# How to stop add_reaction from adding to the count of the poll. discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to create a simple poll with the discord bot. The issue is that when I add a reaction, it adds to the count. Here is my code:

```
poll = await channel.send("Are you going to be there for lunchtime warzone? ")
  
await poll.add_reaction("✅")
await poll.add_reaction("❌")
```

Below is the bot already marking the reactions

[image]

The issue is that it already has both reactions checked and I want the count to be at zero for starting. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where's your code for doing the counting?

Comment: Or do you mean the actual emoji counts you want to be 0? If that's the case, you can't have that be 0 if you want the bot to add the reactions. Discord counts those as reactions.

Comment: @ESloman it’s the second one. I want the emoji count to be zero. Got to know it adds the bots reaction. Is there any way around this or am I stuck with the bots reaction? I basically don’t care for the reactions , just any way to get an accurate poll or headcount.

Comment: I think you're stuck with it; and just have to remove 1 from each when you're having a look at it. You _could_ do something fancy with buttons and edit the message each time to count it manually but that's more work and code and reactions wouldn't be used.

Comment: @ESloman how would I subtract one from each reaction? I thought about it earlier but my google-fu didn’t do me any good

Comment: I mean just by like counting in your head haha. How are you planning on "counting" each one?

Comment: Honestly it’s just meant to be a simple poll to see who is trying to run video games. It’s meant to be more of a headcount thing , but I can see my buddies nagging me that the bot will be showing up lol.

Comment: Yeah fair! Unfortunately nothing you can do with reactions in this case!